# How to use ripple-lib with nativescript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

Dear stackoverflowers,

i'm having troubles with crypto in nativescript.
I want to use a NPM package ripple-lib but found no luck with nativescript-nodeify.
How can I make this package work with nativescript vuejs.
I Need te make use of the crypto package aswell.

**EDIT:**
If i require the package I first get an error -> Error is: Cannot find module '/Websites/repo/tests/FirebaseVuejs/platforms/ios/FirebaseVuejs/app/tns_modules/nativescript-nodeify/patch-npm-packages.js'.

than if i rebuild there is no error and the package is still giving me the same error as i ran it without nativescript-nodeify:

CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/bundle.js:950:22: TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function. (In 'crypto.randomBytes(16)', 'crypto.randomBytes' is undefined)

Comment: Crypto support is included in nodify plug-in. May I know what issues you are facing when implementing ripple?

Comment: I've updated the question. No clue what the problem is.

Comment: As described in [docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify#usage) did you use the require statement (`require("nativescript-nodeify");
`) before importing your ripple-lib?

Comment: Yes doesn't work with different packages as wel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ripple-lib](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib) is using certain dependencies, that use node.js specific or globally available modules and access them via `require` or directly from `global` context. In reality, NativeScript environment is different from both node.js and browser, so we have to make sure all dependencies are met and are available to run in {N} environment.

For many use-cases [nativescript-nodeify](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify) plugin does the job, but case of using `ripple-lib`, it does not resolve the issue so we have to take care of compatibilities manually:

1) `ripple-lib`'s dependency [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) is using native node library [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). Since it is not available in {N} runtime, we have to use specially designed module [nativescript-randombytes](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-randombytes) and make it accessible globally with webpack's [providePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):

1. Add NativeScript plugin to the project:

   ```
   tns plugin add nativescript-randombytes
   ```
2. Create a file that will be a partial implementation of `crypto` module:

   ```
   // Example path: project/app/shims/crypto.js

   module.exports.randomBytes = require('nativescript-randombytes')
   ```
3. Add it to `webpack.config.js` in plugins configuration:

   ```
   plugins: [
     ..., // other plugins
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           crypto: resolve(__dirname, 'app/shims/crypto.js')
       })
   ]
   ```
4. Add `resolve.alias` for our version of `crypto` in `webpack.config.js`, so child dependencies `require` our `crypto` implementation:

   ```
   alias: {
     ..., // Other aliases
     'crypto': resolve(__dirname, 'app/shims/crypto.js')
   }
   ```

2) There are few required modules that are missing, though we can install them manually, as they are compatible with NativeScript runtime:

```
npm i -S lodash bufferutil tls utf-8-validate
```

3) `ripple-lib` doesn't seem to work with available websockets implementation, so we have to use cross-platform solution for NativeScript - [nativescript-websockets](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-websockets)

1. Add plugin to the project:

   ```
   tns plugin add nativescript-websockets
   ```
2. And import it before `ripple-lib` import:

   ```
   import 'nativescript-websockets'
   import { RippleAPI } from 'ripple-lib'
   ```

4) `net` node.js module is also required to establish connection, which can be mocked with webpack [node](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/) mocks configuration. Add the following under `node` config options in `webpack.config.js`:

```
   node: {
        ..., // Other default NativeScript shims 
        "net": 'mock',
    },
```

5) Some libraries are confused about the environment they are running in and default to Node, which makes them request non-available modules. To fix it set [resolve.aliasFields](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-aliasfields) to 'browser', as following:

```
   resolve: {
     // other options, aliases, etc
     aliasFields: ['browser']
   }
```

6) Another library that can't run itself, as it depends on `crypto` module is `create-hash`. Good thing is that it is shipped with a browser build which we can use to fix it. Add another `alias` in `resolve` options for `webpack.config.js`:

```
  alias: {
    ..., // Other aliases
    'create-hash': 'create-hash/browser'
  }
```

7) After all steps are done make sure to clean up project files. Do the following:

1. Delete folders:

   ```
   rm -rf platforms/android # or ios
   rm -rf hooks
   rm -rf node_modules
   ```
2. Reinstall packages and add platforms:

   ```
   npm i
   tns platform add android # or ios
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! the "/" before app should not be there otherwise you'll get an reference error. After that still one error: ERROR in ../node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
[18-12-26 13:00:49.932] (CLI) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net'. And the app wont go pass {N} startup image

Comment: @Dutchdev Thank you for pointing out the typo. In my case `net` was fixed while configuring `axios`, but after a check, you are right. Added another point to fix `net` module issue.

Comment: As much as I wanted it to work, i'm still getting an error signing a payment transaction. CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/bundle.js:1569:22: TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function. (In 'crypto.randomBytes(16)', 'crypto.randomBytes' is undefined)

Comment: Aparently, some libraries still `require` `crypto` module. Please, add the following line, with path according to example above, to `resolve.alias` section of `webpack.config.js`: `'crypto': resolve(__dirname, 'app/shims/crypto.js')`.

Comment: I'm feeling that we are almost there, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'http.get.call')

Comment: Try removing line `"http": false` from `node` options in `webpack.config.js`

Comment: I've got it to the point that it catched the following error `TypeError: createHash is not a function. (In 'createHash('sha512')', 'createHash' is undefined)`

Comment: I've found an issue while working with `secp256k1` algorithm generated keys (which are used by default). Will take a look at your issues as well. Thank you for adding.

Comment: @Dutchev Please, see update answer with steps 5 & 6 to resolve all issues mentioned in comments above.